# What does a "repeat" symbol on the chord section mean?

Tags: chords, sheet-music, repeats

In the following picture, there's a "repeat" symbol on the chord section.

[image: the symbol on the chord section]

I know the meaning of repeat symbols in the measures, but I don’t know what it means in the chord section.

Does it mean to repeat the chord, i.e. Fmaj7 from the second bar?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's confusing because it's unnecessary.  A chord persists until the next one is stated or there's an obvious stop.

Comment: Yes that is why I was confused.

Comment: Some picking or strum patterns may play the start of a chord differently from a continuation; repeating the chord symbol would indicate that it should be played as though it was a new chord.

Comment: I can imagine a use for explicitly stating a repeated chord. For example, it might emphasise that the player should re-play the chord rather than leaving it on sustain. Or it might discourage chord substitutions on beat 1. But IMHO such rigidity is inappropriate for _The Girl From Ipanema_, so I would leave it out here.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this just means to repeat the chord.

It might seem like a needless abbreviation in this case, but some chords can get to be pretty long, in which case this notation is quicker.

Comment: It's unnecessary to repeat the symbol OR to have the repeat sign.

Answer (score 3):

The repeat is referring to the Fmaj7 chord sign, not the dots. As it's on top of the stave, it just means repeat the previous chord. And with one slash, it most likely tells that the Fmaj7 is only for that bar, although there could be another identical sign saying the following bar is also Fmaj7.

Comment: If it was a 2 or 4 bar repeat symbol, it wouldn't be positioned there.

Comment: True. But it could be three!

Comment: Sorry, no cigar again!   If 3-bar repeats existed, there would be 3 bars of data follwed by the symbol over the mid-point of the NEXT 3 bars.